# Arduino send long string to Android

Tags: android, string, bluetooth, arduino

I'm trying to send long String to Android via bluetooth.

but,

[image]

It looks like the picture.

some characters are changed.

how can I get an exact full string?

arduino code :

```
    for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
      String rec = String(P[i], HEX);
      if(rec.length()<2) rec = "0"+rec;
      BTSerial.println(rec);
      delay(50);
```

`P` is a byte array. Thanks.

Comment: in your code a } is missing

Answer (score 1):

Try it without String objects:

```
// return '0' .. 'F'
char hexnibble(byte nibble) {
  nibble &= 0x0F; // just to be sure
  if (nibble > 9) return 'A' + nibble - 10;
  else return '0' + nibble; 
}

void loop() {
 byte P[16]; 
 //  ... fill P somehow ...
 char rec[33];
 for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
      rec[2*i] = hexnibble(P[i] >> 4);
      rec[2*i+1] = hexnibble(P[i] & 0x0F);
 }
 rec[32] = 0; // string terminator

Serial.println(rec); // just for debugging
delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Happy to read it helped, even with the small syntax errror (sorry for that)